# Load login page in wso2 Api store 1.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am thinking of calling a login page whenever wso2 api store first load before showing the list of apis ,, as i am new in jaggeryJs , don't have any idea how to achieve this .

Can anyone please let me know how to get this .??

Thanks

Comment: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/09/customizing-api-store-publisher-part1/ , http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/08/customizing-api-storepublisher-jaggery-applicationspart2/ contains the structure of the jaggery applications used in api manager.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `jaggery.conf` file in store jaggery app root folder. Store jaggery app is located in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps` directory. You have to change below line

`"welcomeFiles":["site/pages/list-apis.jag", "index.html"]`

to

`"welcomeFiles":["site/pages/yourLoginPage.jag", "index.html"]`

in `jaggery.conf` file
and implement your login page in `yourLoginPage.jag`

Comment: Hi Lakshman ,

Is it possible to directly call the existing login functionality .??

Comment: yes that is the thing actually you should do. but  you have to implement new login page because existing login UI is a dialog box not a web page.

Comment: I have implemented a login.jag as per our requirement and then calling ui/dialogs from there..

i can see the login form in there as well as i am able to login successfull,

but for example i have clicked on my subscription before login , i am asked to enter the credentials on login page ,, which is fine ...but when i successfully logged in it stays in login page only(even after logged in ) rather then going to my subscription page ..

Can you please help me out into this so that it can be redirected to specific page instead of staying in login page ..??

Comment: can i have your email id or some IM username so that i can reach you out from there instead of waiting for your reply here .??

Comment: There were some issues with URL redirecting in api store. Could you create a jira on this? for now you can keep the requested url in a variable and redirect to the requested url if login success. you have to implement redirecting to request url(ex: subscription page).

Comment: Problem is resolved by making use of class - need-login which will be append in menu/block.jag for the links where we require login ..

Another problem comes in as when i login and then back button ,, it is going to login page instead of staying on that same page.